# eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return throws error message when using inline require() statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a react native typescript project where I am using inline `require()` statement to import images for example.

```
<Card.Image source={smallPhoto ? { uri: smallPhoto } : require("../../assets/no-photo.png")} style={styles.cardImage} />
```

I'm seeing the following message

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

In react native app what would the return type be for a `require()`

`Card.Image` is coming from `react-native elements`. How do I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 3):

i solve this by declaring as `ImageSourceProps` e.g.

```
    <Image
      source={
        require('../assets/qrcode.png') as ImageSourcePropType
      }
      style={{
        width: 150,
        height: 150
      }}
    />
```